# Custom user properties field in Search folder view

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a custom user property field. I am able to add this field in all folders, except a Search folder.

```
Sub AddStatusProperties()

Dim objNamespace As NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objProperty As UserDefinedProperty
Dim oNameSpace            As Object    'Outlook.Namespace
Dim oStores               As Object    'Outlook.Stores
Dim oStore                As Object    'Outlook.Store
Dim oFolder               As Object    'Outlook.folder

Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For Each objFolder In objNamespace.Folders

    With objFolder.UserDefinedProperties

        Set objProperty = .Add("MyNotes1", olText, True)

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

This is the error message:

> "Run-time error 440: you don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation"

when I added below line.

```
Set oFolder = Session.Stores.Item("xxxxx@xxx.com").GetSearchFolders("Inbox 2")

With oFolder.UserDefinedProperties
Set objProperty = .Add("MyNotes1", olText, True)
End With
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected - folder properties are stored in a hidden (associated) message in the folder. But search folders cannot contains any messages - they only point to the search results from other folders, a message cannot be created there.